# What can we say if expectation and variance tend to 0?

Tags: probability

Let $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of random variables. If we know expectation and variance of $X_n$ tend to $0$. Can we say $X_n$ tends to $0$ weakly? If not, is there any counter example.

Answer (score 2):

Since

$$P(|X_n|>\epsilon) \le E[ \frac{|X_n|^2}{\epsilon^2},|X_n|>\epsilon]\le \frac1{\epsilon^2} E[X_n^2]=\frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \left (\mbox{Var}(X_n)+E[X_n]^2\right). $$

Therefore if both variance and mean tend to zero, then $(X_n)$ converges in probability to zero. This implies convergence in distribution to zero.

Comment: A stronger result is that $X_n\to0$ in $L^2$.

Comment: Much stronger, actually.

Comment: Isn't this answer showing that convergence in probability instead of distribution?